# Overriding password requirements on single location in Apache

Tags: authentication, apache

I have a httpd.conf with authorization, that runs for all parts of an internal website. However, I need to remove the required authorization for one single location.

I've tried using `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` in .htaccess to set "Allow Any" for the location, but it doesn't work, as it still asks for password on the location

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<Location />  
AuthName     "Who are you ?"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType     Basic
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.150.18.101
Allow from 192.168.1.74
Satisfy Any
</Location>

<Location /upload/add_image>
Order allow,deny
Deny from none
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

Comment: This should work, according to countless answers here on SO and all over the web. Except it doesn't, my Apache insists on asking for authentication on the sub/path.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in this situation (from Apache Documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/core.html#location):

> When to use
>
> Use  to apply directives to content that lives outside the filesystem. For  content that lives in the filesystem, use  and . An exception is , which is an easy way to apply a configuration to the entire server.

Because :

> Most importantly,  directives should not be used to control access to filesystem locations. Since several different URLs may map to the same filesystem location, such access controls may by circumvented.

Otherwise, perhaps you can use `<Directory>` (with the correct path) instead `<Location>`.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( It's not actual directories, but mappings in mod_rewrite I'm protecting, so I can't use Directory..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are using some sort of CGI to handle the uploads. This script is, likely, in its own "location", which also needs to be listed with relaxed permissions.

I just had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974096/apache-2-4-how-to-close-entire-site-except-one-subdirectory) -- with Apache 2.4 -- and had to add FastCGI's own prefix (/php-fpm in my case) to the list of Locations with the same (lowered) authz-rules.